# is there a way to use glyphs in a tvml menubar?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, sf-symbols, tvos13

I'm looking for a way to use sf symbols (glyph icons) like `Gear` and `magnifyingglass` inside the menu bar item, instead of a `title`.
Apple talks about it in its [documentation for tvos](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/interface-elements/tab-bars/), but I have not been able to find any reference to tvml js here.

So, Is there any way we could use those icons in the menubar while working in tvml js?